# Redis : SMEMBERS returns 0 after an SMOVE in a MULTI

Tags: transactions, redis

Not sure if I found a bug or multi does not support read/write.
I cannot explain why this would happen ?

MULTI
SMOVE myset1 myset2 mykey
SISMEMBER myset2
EXEC

Ok, +Queued, Queued, 1, 0

Is SISMEMBER read from the same set of data modified during the transaction ?

Comment: Redis documentation does not say anything about where the transaction is executed (http://redis.io/topics/transactions)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not due to MULTI but smove from and to the same set :
https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2517